# How to make glmnet give the same results as glm?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmnet

What parameterization to `glmnet` will give the same results as `glm`?  (I'm mainly interested in logistic and linear regressions, if that matters.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will get the same results as `glm` when you pass `alpha=1` (the default) and `lambda=0`. especially that last one: it means no penalization.

Note that the method of fitting is different in both, so although theoretically you should get the same result, there may still be tiny differences depending on your data.

Comment: `?glmnet` warns about calling it with `lambda` a single value. So to be on the safe side, pass it `0` and another value in a vector.

Comment: glmnet's coordinate descent actually works best when it has a larger range of lambdas, and it can actually be faster to let it calculate the whole regularization path than to go straight to zero. The authors call this giving the algorithm a series of "warm starts". Anyway, my advice is to calculate the whole path with, say, 100 values and pick out lambda==0 at the end.

Comment: Absolutely +1 to what David Harris said. Do not rely on the default values. Running in a simple example -- using the mtcars data, trying to predict mpg based on cyl, hp, wt -- if I use the default lambdas (I don't specify lambda, nlambda, or lambda.min.ratio) I get non-trivial discrepancies. (Intercept 38.00658324 vs 38.75179, for instance.) When I put in 100 or 1000 lambdas the discrepancies between glm and glmnet shrink by 5+ orders of magnitude.

Comment: Also, Nick, the value of alpha is irrelevant, it's the lambda=0 that matters.

Comment: @Paul-Eastlund: to be precise, alpha is irrelevant **when lambda=0**. (otherwise it's very relevant)

Comment: I get this error message: `from glmnet Fortran code (error code -77); Convergence for 77th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned`. How do I force `glmnet` to use `lambda=0`?

Answer (score 1):

Although unregularized `glmnet` *should* behave like `glm`, `glmnet` will override `lambda=0` in some circumstances. It's safer to use the base `glm` function, especially if you're training a large number of models.

```
x <- structure(c(0.028, 0.023, 0.0077, 0.14, 0.027, 0.084, 0.018, 
                 0.055, 0.0089, 0.016, 0.037, 0.043, 0.046, 0.031, 0.034, 0.056, 
                 0.016, 0.048, 0.013, 0.02, 0.067, 0.046, 0.058, 0.054, 0.036, 
                 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 0.018, 0.066, 0.046, 0.057, 0.054, 
                 0.036, 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 0.018, 0.051, 0.043, 0.047, 
                 0.045, 0.034, 0.04, 0.009, 0.085, 0.022, 0.016, 0.028, 0.023, 
                 0.0089, 0.14, 0.028, 0.084, 0.02, 0.055, 0.0089, 0.016, 0.067, 
                 0.049, 0.058, 0.055, 0.038, 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 0.018, 
                 0.067, 0.046, 0.058, 0.054, 0.036, 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 
                 0.018), .Dim = c(10L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
y <- gl(2, 5)
fit <- glmnet::glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", lambda = 0)
fit$lambda # should be 0 but actually infinity
```

```
Warning messages:
1: In lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground
2: from glmnet Fortran code (error code -1); Convergence for 1th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
3: In getcoef(fit, nvars, nx, vnames) :
  an empty model has been returned; probably a convergence issue
```